# redirect www to non-www url magento

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect

My site is running with non-www urls and when i open any inner page with www in url it redirects me to home page.

I have made below changes in .htacess at the top

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.test.in [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.in/$1 [L,R=301]
```

but didn't work,

I also set up 
Auto-redirect to Base URL to No from admin

can someone give me solution that how can i redirect www to non-www urls for homepage and inner pages as well without redirecting inner pages to home page

Comment: The rule looks good, so there must be something else. When you request `http://www.test.in`, does it redirect properly to `http://test.in`?

Comment: @OlafDietsche when i add www in home page like http://www.test.in then it's opening home page with same url with www

and when i access any inner page with www it redirects me to home page without www in url

Comment: @OlafDietsche brother can you solve my problem??

Comment: Unfortunately not, maybe it's the browser's cache or some other rules, which interfere.

Comment: @OlafDietsche thanks anyways, i will contact to my hosting provider

Answer (score 0):

it will be like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.test.in$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://test.in/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: no it's still redirecting to home page if i open inner page with www in url

Comment: i want code for redirection of www url to non-www url i think you are giving me non-www to www direction code.

Comment: for megento you can do it in easy way check this link out https://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://cdn.inmotionhosting.com/support/images/stories/magento/changing-unsecure-base-url-magento.png&imgrefurl=http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/magento/how-to-change-url&h=483&w=667&tbnid=5yM2SJw3PK5w8M:&vet=1&tbnh=152&tbnw=211&docid=m7ih8cKiBXn8kM&usg=__X1DLELarGpsIE4dWXq3mt6MWARg=&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8h5PZvufSAhXFK48KHW0DD6cQ9QEIOTAA#h=483&imgrc=5yM2SJw3PK5w8M:&tbnh=152&tbnw=211&vet=1&w=667

Comment: still inner pages redirecting to home page if i open any inner page with www

Comment: try this https://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://cdn.inmotionhosting.com/support/images/stories/magento/changing-unsecure-base-url-magento.png&imgrefurl=http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/magento/how-to-change-url&h=483&w=667&tbnid=5yM2SJw3PK5w8M:&vet=1&tbnh=152&tbnw=211&docid=m7ih8cKiBXn8kM&usg=__X1DLELarGpsIE4dWXq3mt6MWARg=&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8h5PZvufSAhXFK48KHW0DD6cQ9QEIOTAA#h=483&imgrc=5yM2SJw3PK5w8M:&tbnh=152&tbnw=211&vet=1&w=667

Comment: yes but i have set there url without www so i want to make direct rule from www to non-www urls using htacess

Comment: cache is disabled

Answer (score 0):

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.test.in [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.in/$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: dude check my question i am already using this piece of code but it's not working